# Android add text to textview programmaticaly

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a question.
I'm passing multiple string from json into another activity and show it there.
The question is, how can I add a comma between two string?

I want its show like this.
[image: Sample Picture]

What I got now is, there's no comma between $$$ and Italian text.

And another question is, is it possible to use just one textview?
Because I use a single textview for each text.

Here's my java code

#### Food.java

```
String cuisine_name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cuisine_name))
                    .getText().toString();
String price_category = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price_category))
                    .getText().toString();

Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    FoodDetail.class);
            in.putExtra("TAG_CUISINE_NAME", cuisine_name);
            in.putExtra("TAG_PRICE_CATEGORY", price_category);
```

#### FoodDetail.java

```
    TextView cuisine_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodsCuisine);
    TextView price_category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodsPriceCategory);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    String cuisine = in.getStringExtra("TAG_CUISINE_NAME");
    String priceCategory = in.getStringExtra("TAG_PRICE_CATEGORY");

    cuisine_name.setText(cuisine);
    price_category.setText(priceCategory);
```

Thanks before :D

Comment: `cuisine_name.setText(cuisine + ", " + priceCategory);` and remove `price_category` TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

Intent in = getIntent();
String cuisine = in.getStringExtra("TAG_CUISINE_NAME");
String priceCategory = in.getStringExtra("TAG_PRICE_CATEGORY");

textview.setText(cuisine+","+priceCategory);
```

Comment: `","priceCategory` is missing `+` in between

Comment: I already fix like @PratikButani said. And there's no error.But its still not working. Its still print $$$Italian.

Comment: @user3561934,now check i have edited my ans and is my mistake to forgot "+".

Comment: can you please explain more about it.

Comment: Like I explain on my question. I got the data from json parser.
Show it on listview, and when I click one of the item it'll open new activity that contains the detail of the item. My question above is about the detail of the item. But on the listview, its still show $$$Italia.

Comment: @user3561934 Its my pleasure, You till forgot space after comma like `", "`.

Comment: well, I'm using list adapter like this to put it into textview.
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Food.this, restaurantList,
                    R.layout.foodlayout, new String[] { TAG_CUISINE_NAME, TAG_PRICE_CATEGORY
                      }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.cuisine_name, R.id.price_category});

Can I put it in there?
Or I have to declare it before the list adapter?

Comment: @user3561934 see my updated answer and if it will help you, dont forget to upvote ;)

Comment: Try to concatenate this TAG_CUISINE_NAME+","TAG_PRICE_CATEGORY string before assign string array to adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Its just simple as this.

```
cuisine_price.setText(priceCategory+","+cuisine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take just one `TextView`

```
TextView cuisine_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodsCuisine);
//Make here comment
//TextView price_category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodsPriceCategory);
```

and Set Value like:

```
Intent in = getIntent();
String cuisine = in.getStringExtra("TAG_CUISINE_NAME");
String priceCategory = in.getStringExtra("TAG_PRICE_CATEGORY");

cuisine_name.setText(cuisine + ", " + priceCategory); // ", " is matters here....
```

#### Update:

For your ListView Adapter:

Change parameter of `String[]` and `int[]`:

```
new String[] { TAG_CUISINE_NAME , TAG_PRICE_CATEGORY }, new int[] {R.id.cuisine_name, R.id.price_category}
```

to

```
new String[] { TAG_CUISINE_NAME + ", " + TAG_PRICE_CATEGORY }, new int[] {R.id.cuisine_name}
```

Like:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Food.this, restaurantList, R.layout.foodlayout, new String[] { TAG_CUISINE_NAME + ", " + TAG_PRICE_CATEGORY }, new int[] { R.id.cuisine_name});
```

may it will be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying your ans. but its not working. is it because I have more that two string?
I still have another string like item_name, phone, etc like that.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have two different textviews, and if you will always show values to these textviews in the same order then start from the first textview and add:

```
cuisine_name.setText(cuisine + ", ");
price_category.setText(priceCategory + ", ");
anotherTextview.setText(somethingHere);
```

(and here on the last one simply dont put a comma)

Now if you have 1 textview to show all values then insert manually a comma inbetween the values:

```
aTextView.setText(cuisine + ", " + priceCategory + ", " + somethingHere);
```